# PyQGIS: Add threshold value based on user input in Raster Calculator

Tags: pyqgis, raster-calculator, expression, formula

I want to use Raster Calculator in my Python script in QGIS. The expression is easy - I want to create a new raster with two values (0,1) where I get 1 if the pixel value is higher than a certain threshold ("A > minimum index"). The **minimum index** is **user define**.

Does anybody know how to add a variable as a parameter into an expression?

[image]

Below is my code:

```
       from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
       from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                       QgsFeatureSink,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink,
                       QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer,
                       QgsProcessingParameterNumber,
                       QgsRasterLayer)
        from qgis import processing

        class ExampleProcessingAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):        
        
        INPUT = 'INPUT'
        THRESHOLD = 'THRESHOLD'
        OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'

        def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
       
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer(
                self.INPUT,
                self.tr('NDVI Layer'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeRaster]
            )
        )
        
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterNumber(
            self.THRESHOLD,
            self.tr('Minimum Index'),
            QgsProcessingParameterNumber.Double
            )
        )
        
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
                self.OUTPUT,
                self.tr('Output layer')
            )
        )

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        
        calc = processing.run('gdal:rastercalculator',
            {'INPUT_A':parameters[self.INPUT],
            'BAND_A':1,
            'INPUT_B':parameters[self.THRESHOLD],
            'FORMULA': '(A > B)',
            'OUTPUT':parameters[self.OUTPUT]
            },
            context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
             
        index = calc['OUTPUT']
        
        return {self.OUTPUT: index}
```

this is the error message:

> Could not load source layer for INPUT_B: 0.37 not found
> Execution failed after 0.02 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use 'INPUT_B' parameter as that is for additional raster inputs.

The simplest way to insert the value of your threshold input parameter into the raster calc expression is to use Python string formatting. [F-Strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python) are a great way to do this. So, your `processAlgorithm()` method could look like:

```
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
    
    calc = processing.run('gdal:rastercalculator',
        {'INPUT_A':parameters[self.INPUT],
        'BAND_A':1,
        'FORMULA': f'(A > {parameters[self.THRESHOLD]})',
        'OUTPUT':parameters[self.OUTPUT]
        },
        context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
         
    index = calc['OUTPUT']

    return {self.OUTPUT: index}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It solved my problem :) May you live a long and healthy life

Comment: @Siti, you're welcome. Thank you for the kind wishes:-)